# Java: Accessing same ArrayList while using the rest of the elements in that ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, mybatis

I have a database table that has following structure: And for this post purpose I would like to call the table as `MixUserTable`

```
id, user_id, partner_id
1, 333cx1, s12z
2, 333xx1, r23z
3, r23z, t32q
```

I have a different process getting an array list containing list of ids which has a mixer of `user_id`, and `partner_id`.

I am trying to iterate over the ArrayList that contains mixture of ids and want to confirm if each of the element in ArrayList has pairs in the database. But to do that I have to access multiple elements to make the database call.

Here is the approach I was trying to do:

I first make a copy of the ArrayList that I have been passed on: then I iterate over original one and its copy to check if the pair exist:

```
ArrayList<UserDAO> tempPeople = new ArrayList<UserDAO>();
tempPeople = originalArrayList

for(UserDAO user : originalArrayList) {
  for (UserDAO copyUser : tempPeople) {
    if(!user.getId().equals(copyUser.getId())) {
      //select * from mixuser where user_id = 'someUvalue' and partner_id = 'otherUserValue'
      MixUserDAO mixUser = (MixUserDAO)myBatisUtil.select(myBatisUtil.MIXUSERDAO, "select", queryParams);
      if(mixUser != null) {
        Do something like update etc
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is this a good way to handle this type of situation, and avoid exceptions like `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

If not what would be the better way to handle this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of ConcurrentModificationException is here:

```
tempPeople = originalArrayList
```

when you execute this code, you declare a pointer to originalArrayList. Correct code should be:

```
tempPeople = new ArrayList(originalArrayList)
```

**Update**
more precise example:

```
String userIDs = "";
for(UserDAO user : originalArrayList) {
  userIDs += user.getId() + ",";
}
userIDs = userIDs.substring(0, userIDs.length-1); //remove last ','

//select * from mixuser where user_id in (list) and partner_id in (list)
MixUserDAO mixUser = (MixUserDAO)myBatisUtil.select(myBatisUtil.MIXUSERDAO, "select", userIDs);
```

in myBatis xml mapper:

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="domain.blog.MixUserDAO" parameterType="java.lang.String">
  select * from mixuser
  WHERE user_id in ('#{value}') and partner_id in ('#{value}')
</select>
```

You'll get all users which have both userID and parentID in the originalArrayList.

Comment: Maybe better approach will be in one request: "select * from mixuser where user_id in (list) and partner_id in (list)". You'll get all you need.

Comment: could you please explain little bit more? What you are saying is instead of running two loops just send the lists in to the query?

Comment: just to confirm parameterType in myBatis XML mapper would be string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58574/discussion-between-aliaksei-and-null-hypothesis).